# Постеры к видео

Tags: php

Как в php 7 загрузить видео и сразу же сделать скирншот видео по середине видео и сохранить его(создать постер к видео) без сторонних ffmepg и т.п., загрузка файла(видео) понятна а вот чтоб еще и при загрузке создавал постер к видео без сторонних библиотек не понято

Comment: А чем вам мешает разобрать библиотеку `ffmpeg-php`? И сделать на ее основе себе, что хотите.

Comment: Потому что как я понял нет ffmepg на php 7

Comment: и к тому же у меня windows 10

Comment: Ну так разберите и сделайте для `php7`. Нам что за вас это делать.

Comment: @Gradusnik [под php7](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) - вроде как

Comment: В поисковиках можно найти много документации. Одно время сам был этим заинтересован.